# What would would be the best controller for a custom gateway page for a community?

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component

I am trying to write a custom VForce page for a Community landing page so after users login they can see the main sections of the Community and click on the links and then go to the page layouts view. Is this possible and what kind of controller would I need and would it be custom or standard? I would guess custom.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this post [Customize communities login page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17054/customize-communities-login-page/17633#17633) which I think will provide you with the instructions and code that I believe you're looking for.

Depending on whether or not you plan to use SSO, you may also want to refer to the following links as well: [How to create a custom login page in salesforce.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643253/how-to-create-a-custom-login-page-in-salesforce-com), [Using frontdoor.jsp to login to Salesforce UI and Communities](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000193348&language=en_US) and the following [Help page](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=security_frontdoorjsp.htm).

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to implement your own custom Communities homepage in Visualforce and the page requires a logic layer in apex, you would need a custom controller. If you don't require apex at all, you don't need a controller at all.

Comment: I read his question entirely different than you did. I didn't pick up on him asking about a custom community home page. Will be interesting to read any clarification on the question.