# Communities Redirect Apex

Tags: apex, community, urlhacking, redirect

I have a site called support.domain.com lives in one org

And i have build a community with same content called support.domain.com/s/ in different org

i am trying to retraid the old site and use the community instead

so i want to redirect all user that have the old Urls to get to the new ones

Example--- OLD Site: support.domain.com/articles/pagename to
NEW Community: support.domain.com/s/article/pagename

so i am just wondering if it's possible using code apex to mape it or entering every URL into salesforce one at a time

Comment: Does this site use VF pages?

Comment: @JitenderPadda Yes

Answer (score 0):

Just add a script on the page to redirect -

```
let url = window.location.href;
url = url.replace("/articles","/s/article");
window.location.replace(url);
```

> With replace() the current page will not be saved in session History,
> meaning the user won't be able to use the back button to navigate to
> it - [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace#:~:text=The%20replace()%20method%20of,button%20to%20navigate%20to%20it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace#:%7E:text=The%20replace()%20method%20of,button%20to%20navigate%20to%20it).

Comment: There is any way to do the redirection in the community instead old site VF page since we will get retired the VF page in the future?

Comment: I mean in the communities landing controller

Comment: Okay, in that case, if you want to redirect them during login you could try this answer - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17054/customize-communities-login-page. Make sure the PageReference url you enter is the full URL for your new site.